# Change appearance of combo box at run time in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have a requirement that a component should look like a combo box when it has more than one values and like a textfield when it has only one value.

Instead of changing the component. I am choosing to just change the cls of that component that will make it look like a combo box or a textfield at the run time depending on the no of items in a combobox.

To do that I am using the following

```
comboBox.removeCls('comboBoxWithNoImg');
comboBox.addCls('comboBoxWithImg');
```

But it is not working. When I inspect it at this point,it shows the changed cls in the watch (debugger) but not on the UI.
Also, it seems that it is not getting refreshed or something.

I also tried the following :

```
comboBox.cls = 'comboBoxWithImg';
comboBox.initialCls = 'comboBoxWithImg';
comboBox.listConfig.cls = 'comboBoxWithImg';
comboBox.initialConfig.cls= 'comboBoxWithImg';
comboBox.fieldCls= 'comboBoxWithImg';
```

But its not changing on the UI.

Please help, I have put in a lot of time on this issue...:(
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to hide and show the arrow icon that is displayed with a combo box then you can call the **hide** and **show** functions on the combo box's [triggerEl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Trigger-method-hide) as shown below

```
comboBox.triggerEl.hide();
comboBox.triggerEl.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want combobox just to look like a regular textfield you can hide trigger

`comboBox.setHideTrigger(true);`